# GatewayScript request and not wait for response

Tags: node.js, ibm-datapower

Is it possible to make a GET/POST call to an external rest API and not wait for the response?

Answer (score -1):

GatewayScript urlopen has a callback so you can't just "ignore" the callback I'd assume, at least I can't think of a way to do that..
The callback takes two params, `error` and `response` and if you don't give them you'll get an error.

```
urlopen.open('http://example.com/mydoc.json', function (error, response) {
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the request is still synchronous.

Comment: I tested it, it still blocks the processing of the original request (the one that triggered the script), until the `urlopen` request is finished. It may be async in the context of the specific script, but it still blocks throughput.

Comment: No, you can run multiple threads in GWS, there's no blocking, just as in node.js. GWS is a Node.js core, with a few things stripped out.

Answer (score -2):

Use an asynchronous call like fetch, await or promise like below:

```
fetch(myRequest)
.then(function(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
  }
  return response.blob();
})
.then(function(response) {
  //retrieve your data her from the response object
});
```

Comment: DataPower has its own implementation of modules/functions. Fetch is not supported.